# Switching between the web cameras in Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to build an application in which user can switch between the web cameras connected. On start default web cam should load which is working good. After that user has an option to switch between the cameras. When I try to do so, the quad on which i am trying to put the web cam texture projected is becoming black when i called the other camera for second time. I have attached debug.log to see weather the camera is detected or not, the camera is detecting. Can anyone tell me where i am making mistake. below is the code that calls web camera two.

```
public void camTwo()
    {
        WebCamDevice[] cam_devices = WebCamTexture.devices;
        WebCamTexture webcamTexture = new WebCamTexture(cam_devices[1].name);
        webcamTexture.Stop();
        if (webcamTexture == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("web cam not found");
        }
        else
          {
            Debug.Log("camera found");
          }
        Renderer renderer = e.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        renderer.material.mainTexture = webcamTexture;
        webcamTexture.Play();
    }
```

Comment: may i know why the question is down rated. can you please tell me what other details needed.

Comment: Please use the correct tags! `unityscript` is or better was a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long deprecated by now! Your script is clearly `c#`!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes textures can be black if the material on them is set to black. Also, is there a light in your scene? If you the texture is on a 3D object (like a plane or cube), you will need a light source to be able to see it. Rather than create a webCamTexture programmatically, I might create the Texture you are piping the camera to manually in the GUI, and use that to show the WebCam(it is easier to see it's properties and edit them).